# OpenCV length of matches in BFMatcher

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use SIFT on two images and match the keypoints using BFMatcher in OpenCV.

However, the number of matches is not equal to the number of query descriptors. Can someone explain why they are not equal?

According to [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d39/classcv_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html#a0f046f47b68ec7074391e1e85c750cba)
`match()` function **"Finds the best match for each descriptor from a query set."**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im1 = cv2.imread("trex1.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im2 = cv2.imread("trex2.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(im1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(im2, None)

im_kp1 = np.zeros(im1.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
im_kp2 = np.zeros(im1.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
im_kp1 = cv2.drawKeypoints(im1,kp1,None)
im_kp2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(im2,kp2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

print len(des1)
# Result : 78
print len(des2)
# Result : 71
print len(matches)
# Result : 55
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `crossCheck=True` is removing some of the results.

If you check the [docs for the `BFMatcher()` constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/da1/classcv_1_1BFMatcher.html#ac6418c6f87e0e12a88979ea57980c020):

> **crossCheck** If it is false, this is will be default BFMatcher behaviour when it finds the k nearest neighbors for each query descriptor. If crossCheck==true, then the knnMatch() method with k=1 will only return pairs (i,j) such that for i-th query descriptor the j-th descriptor in the matcher's collection is the nearest and vice versa, i.e. the BFMatcher will only return consistent pairs. Such technique usually produces best results with minimal number of outliers when there are enough matches. This is alternative to the ratio test, used by D. Lowe in SIFT paper.

This reads like it will only affect the `knnMatch()` method, but the `match()` methods actually [explicitly call `knnMatch()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/f5dba12762b8878bbb940e16a3ca07fa0a0b5c2a/modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp):

> ```
> void DescriptorMatcher::match( InputArray queryDescriptors, std::vector<DMatch>& matches, InputArrayOfArrays masks )
> {
>     CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION()
>
>     std::vector<std::vector<DMatch> > knnMatches;
>     knnMatch( queryDescriptors, knnMatches, 1, masks, true /*compactResult*/ );
>     convertMatches( knnMatches, matches );
> }
> ```

If you set `crossCheck=False` (or just don't specify, it's `False` by default), then you'll get

```
len(query_descriptors) == len(matches)
```